# Why didn't Voldemort hide his Horcruxes on different planets?

Tags: harry-potter

Voldemort could have travelled to different planets. Muggles landed on the moon, I think Wizards could do that easily.

Why didn't Voldemort hide his Horcruxes on the Moon and/or other planets?

Comment: You'll need evidence to show that such a thing is possible, beyond your own opinion.

Comment: The only way for wizards to travel to other planets is by harnessing air spirits known as sylphs. Sylphs are flighty, true to their nature, and can only be urged to do anything by a combination of positive reinforcement (sylph esteem) and negative reinforcement (sylph abuse). Neither of which are reliable enough to necessarily trust a trip through the airless void of space.

Comment: I've voted to close as a dupe because the other question addresses the wider issue of wizards traveling into space *per se*.

Comment: Then Harry has to take help from Avengers to destroy it.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no evidence that wizards can leave Earth**.

Simply: Voldemort didn't hide his Horcruxes on Mars, because he had no way to get there.

In fact, there's only a single reference to space travel in the entire series:

> He flicked through the rest of the magazine. Pausing every few pages he read an accusation that the Tuthill Tornados were winning the Quidditch League by a combination of blackmail, illegal broom-tampering, and torture; an interview with a wizard who claimed to have flown to the moon on a Cleansweep Six and brought back a bag of moon frogs to prove it; and an article on ancient runes, which at least explained why Luna had been reading The Quibbler up-side down.
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, chapter 10: "Luna Lovegood"</sub>

We can tell from this that space travel is... not common among wizards, any more than it is among Muggles.

Comment: I don't think that really confirms space travel by "claiming" and "proving with moon frogs" Also, isn't the Quibbler a (mock) wizard version of the National Enquirer?

Comment: We have confirmation from JKR that wizards are (potentially) from Mars; http://web.archive.org/web/20110514102401/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm

Comment: @TurkuSama - of course. I'm giving it as an example of why space travel *isn't* common; there's only one mention of space travel, and it's by a crackpot

Comment: @Valorum Actually the only reference to Mars there says "Hambledon Quince: Author of controversial theory that wizards originate from Mars, Muggles from mushrooms."

Comment: @RalfFriedl - Some people choose to believe otherwise, I'll admit

Comment: Is it necessary to travel to space to place a Horcrux in space?